# Patches that Account for Margins

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to add a patch to a plot that takes into account axis margins. The purpose of the patch is to allow for transparent plots with a filled plot area (such that the patch fills the entire plot area.)

the margins for ax are: `(0.04, 0.05)`

The code I use to add the patch:

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((xlim[0], ylim[0]), xlim[1] - xlim[0], ylim[1] - ylim[0], facecolor=plot_area_color, zorder=1))
```

I can't find a way to account for the margins.  Or, is there an alternate way to set a savefig kwarg `transparent=True` *and* have the plot area be filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon an answer that seems to be working well for me.  The key was to change the patch from plotting based on the X and Y limits and rather based on the coordinate system.  The addition of an attribute `transform=ax.transAxes` to my patch code has solved my problem.

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, transform=ax.transAxes, facecolor=plot_area_color, zorder=1))
```

For my purpose (transparent chart with filled plot area), the coordinate system is particularly well suited.